# Simple C Oddity

Tags: c

This little bit of C code is driving me nuts. It asks for the Input Voltage but then it skips Resistor 1 and asks for Resistor 2. I'm missing something extremely obvious here... What the heck is going on...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    float Vin;
    int R1;  
    int R2;

    printf("Input Voltage: ");
    scanf("%.3f", &Vin);

    printf("\nResistor 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &R1);

    printf("\nResistor 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &R2);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Barely anything about this code is C++.

Comment: I see no C++ here except including a header for no reason.

Comment: ok...that was just left over from previous work. I've simplified this.

Comment: Removing the C++ tag as it has no bearing on the question.

Comment: @codedude You should not be using `scanf()`. `fgets()` and `strtood()` instead.

Comment: The posted code is valid C++.  It just uses `stdio.h` instead of `iostream`

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Yes but there is nothing C++ specific about it that would warrant the tag.

Comment: @JesusRamos: The same argument could be used to say there's nothing C-specific either, since the code is valid C++.

Comment: It was the .3f in the scanf that was causing my problem. For some reason I must have been thinking it was printf when I typed that

Comment: You're right about that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `.3` part:

```
scanf("%f", &Vin);
```

It does not really make sense to configure the number of decimal digits for input :) Therefore, `scanf` does not support it. A `float` always has 8 decimal digits. Crank up your compiler's warning levels.

Comment: ...why? I need 3 decimal places

Comment: you only really need that in printf

Answer (score 5):

If you turn on `-Wall` on your compiler you receive the warnings:

> warning: unknown conversion type character '.' in format [-Wformat]
>
> warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

So just remove the .3 from `scanf`.

Answer (score 3):

Use simple %f. Here is sample:

```
printf("Input Voltage: ");
scanf("%f", &Vin);

printf("\nResistor 1: ");
scanf("%d", &R1);

printf("\nResistor 2: ");
scanf("%d", &R2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Shooting from the hip here - my gut says that the first `scanf` is being "satisfied" by your input string, there's input left over, and the second `scanf` is getting everything up to the newline.

Try replacing the first format string in with `"%f"` and see whether it still happens. Alternatively, print out the values of voltage and R1 when you see the goofy behavior. It's probably better to worry about rounding/truncating the voltage input after you read it, anyway.